# Is Touch of Evil (1958) the first movie to allow actors to drive vehicles?

Tags: first-appearance

Recently I watched the movie *Touch of Evil* (1958), in which Mike Vargus was really driving vehicles with a moving real background:

[image]

Usually in classic movies, they put running background and the actor pretends they are driving in a car. Was *Touch of Evil* the first movie where this didn't happen?

Comment: Seems unlikely.

Comment: Isn't that scene shot by towing the car on a trailer behind the camera truck?  He isn't driving.

Comment: Muuuuch older and features an actor actually driving a car (and Chaplin riding a motorbike): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPCeHXq7pNQ This kind of question is impossible to answer since most likely the earliest movies featured actors actually driving cars etc. and plenty of them are lost.

Comment: Keystone Cops for one....